# Apache Commons NET: Should I create a new FTPClient object on each connection or reuse one?

Tags: java, android, performance, ftp-client, apache-commons-net

I'm just wondering: in my Java application, each time I need to connect to an FTP server, should I create a new FTPClient object, or should I create one FTPClient() object and re-use that each time I connect to an FTP server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reusing would be better since you wont need a new instance every time you are creating a new connection, even to a new server. Because the connect and disconnect methods can do the job for you.

So reuse as many objects as you can.

Comment: Thank you, was just making sure :)

Comment: However, if you want to make simultaneous connections you'd probably need multiple instances.

Comment: Do you have any data on the cost of creating a new instance, or is this just a guess?

Comment: Thanks, but I only need to connect to one FTP at a time :)

Answer (score 17):

Both will work, but apache commons.net libraries are [not thread safe](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/COMMONS/Net+FrequentlyAskedQuestions), so if you do use one client with multiple threads, be aware that you'll have to synchronize access to it.

Answer (score 4):

Without knowing exactly what your code has to do (how often it connects, how many files it needs to transfer etc) it's difficult to say.

My personal opinion would be one `FTPClient()` but connect/authenticate/transfer/disconnect each time you need to do something (assuming there will be a reasonable gap in between). The reasoning is that FTP sessions often have fairly short inactivity time-outs.